# Did the Taaffe family maintain an actual connection with Ireland during the 19th century?

Tags: 19th-century, ireland, austria

The [Taaffe family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscount_Taaffe) is rather remarkable for having held both an Irish/UK and Austrian peerage. However, it is not clear from the wiki pages whether they (for example, [Count Eduard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eduard_Taaffe), who was Austrian prime-minister for a while) really maintained tangible ties to Ireland. Some questions for example:

1. Did they have Irish estates?
2. Did members of the family visit Ireland?
3. Did they have strongly held and/or publicized views on issues of Irish politics? (like Home Rule)

Answer (score 3):

I found a very interesting source — a Ph.D. thesis by Mag. Lisa Ferris entitled [“Irish Views on Old Austria and Austrian Views on the Irish Question, 1848 – 1918”](http://othes.univie.ac.at/1195/1/2008-09-03_8305662.pdf) devoted to the study of Irish in Austria. (It’s 775 pages long!) Here is a bit from page 19 (page 104 of the PDF document):

> The Taaffes, although almost completely integrated in Austria, never
>   forgot their homeland; [Nicolas Taaffe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas_Taaffe,_6th_Viscount_Taaffe) retained his title even if not
>   all his lands in Ireland. In the Austrian Empire he had been made
>   Field Marshal and Count, as well as serving as Chancellor to Emperor
>   Leopold, but he was still concerned about the “Catholic Question” in
>   Ireland, and in 1766 he published a tract entitled ‘Observations on
>   Affairs in Ireland’, calling for generous treatment of Catholics in
>   Ireland.

Answer (score -1):

My 2nd Great Grandfather was Francis Taaffe born 1844 Ireland and died 1934 in Michigan.  His father's name was James Taaffe.  I have been trying to track down his father in Ireland who died in the early 1850's. Not sure if he died in the FAMINE or over in England, Manchester? 1853  Did Irish men go to England for work during the FAMINE years?

Doug Mills/Michigan

Comment: You should not ask new questions as answers to other questions - the question is easy to miss and answers would be confusing when mixed with answers to the original question.

Comment: Instead, please ask a new question.

Comment: Please ask a new question. And when you ask that question, please clarify why you have formatted FAMINE as an acronym.